# Python Plotly Gauge Threshold Label

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a simple gauge with a threshold, is there a way I can add a label to the threshold?

Below is some sample code from plotly to show the type of gauge and threshold I'm using.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
    mode = "gauge+number+delta",
    value = 420,
    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
    title = {'text': "Speed", 'font': {'size': 24}},
    delta = {'reference': 400, 'increasing': {'color': "RebeccaPurple"}},
    gauge = {
        'axis': {'range': [None, 500], 'tickwidth': 1, 'tickcolor': "darkblue"},
        'bar': {'color': "darkblue"},
        'bgcolor': "white",
        'borderwidth': 2,
        'bordercolor': "gray",
        'steps': [
            {'range': [0, 250], 'color': 'cyan'},
            {'range': [250, 400], 'color': 'royalblue'}],
        'threshold': {
            'line': {'color': "red", 'width': 4},
            'thickness': 0.75,
            'value': 490}}))

fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor = "lavender", font = {'color': "darkblue", 'family': "Arial"})

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution isn't perfect, but if we assume the gauge is roughly a perfect semicircle centered at around `(0.5, 0.1)` in terms of plotly's paper coordinates, then we can place an annotation at roughly the location of the threshold using polar coordinates.

Note that depending on how you resize the browser window, the gauge may become more elliptical so the annotation may move slightly.

```
from numpy import pi, cos, sin
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
    mode = "gauge+number+delta",
    value = 420,
    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
    title = {'text': "Speed", 'font': {'size': 24}},
    delta = {'reference': 400, 'increasing': {'color': "RebeccaPurple"}},
    gauge = {
        'axis': {'range': [None, 500], 'tickwidth': 1, 'tickcolor': "darkblue"},
        'bar': {'color': "darkblue"},
        'bgcolor': "white",
        'borderwidth': 2,
        'bordercolor': "gray",
        'steps': [
            {'range': [0, 250], 'color': 'cyan'},
            {'range': [250, 400], 'color': 'royalblue'}],
        'threshold': {
            'line': {'color': "red", 'width': 4},
            'thickness': 0.75,
            'value': 490}}))

## the center  centered at roughly (0.5,0.05)
## x = r*cos(theta), y = r*sin(theta)
threshold_radians = pi * (500-490) / 500
r = 0.35
dx = r*cos(threshold_radians)
dy = r*sin(threshold_radians)

fig.add_annotation(
    x=0.5+dx, y=0.08+dy,
    xref='paper',yref='paper',
    text="Label",
    font=dict(size=15),
    showarrow=False
)

fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor = "lavender", font = {'color': "darkblue", 'family': "Arial"})

fig.show()
```

[image]